# High response time every 10-12 pings

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ping

I'm at the end of my rope trying to figure out a network issue I'm having with my Windows 10 desktop PC. I have recently noticed latency issues while watching video online or playing video games. My overall speed tests seem fine, however, pinging shows a different story. I have a very low response time typically, but the ping time spikes every 10-12 pings like clockwork. This results in the ping either timing out or being very high (3000+ ms). This issue is not present on my laptop (running Windows 10/Linux), or on any of our mobile devices. An example of the ping issue:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 -t

Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=54
Request timed out.
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=3481ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=54
Request timed out.
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Request timed out.
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=54
Request timed out.
```

What has changed:

- I moved a few cities over from an apartment to a house.
- I installed a new USB WiFi receiver (old USB WiFi receiver is still installed inside my case but is disabled in device manager)

What I have tried:

- Installing all Windows updates
- Changing DNS settings
- Disabled new adapter and tried the old adapter
- ipconfig renew and release
- Disabling all startup items
- Safe mode with networking (note: this was ineffective for testing as I only 
  have WiFi to connect with and safe mode did not load WiFi drivers)

I'm at my wit's end trying to figure this out because it is rendering certain online activities useless. Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried pinging other addresses?

Comment: Similar issues on MACOS, turned out it was wifi scanning causing it.....https://superuser.com/questions/1142798/experiencing-high-latency-on-wifi-every-other-second-with-macos-sierra?rq=1

Comment: The regularity of the issue does suggest something software based causing the issue. You couldn’t run in safe mode but you can certainly disable all non-Microsoft services with msconfig. Also disabling all startup items will be preferred during this test.

Comment: I tried disabling all non-Microsoft services with msconfig, but unfortunately, the issue still persists. This was a good idea, regardless.

Comment: WiFi scanning could be part of it...how can I investigate to see if determine if something is doing this?

Comment: Can you try plugging the system in with an Ethernet cable and see if the problem goes away?

Comment: The router is not very close to where the machine is. I could move the desktop but the router is in a tight spot

Comment: By trying to use an Ethernet cable it might help work out if its a software problem.